# Displaying images from JSON object when image path is missing

Tags: javascript, json

I have a problem displaying images from JSON. My problem specifically is that I have images stored in   a JSON object, however a path 'pointing' to those images is missing.

My approach to display the images is as follows:

```
function populateMenuItems(menuitems){

        // function argument is a JSON object

        var container = $('.container');

        // iterating through JSON object
        for(var i=0; i<menuitems.length; i++){

            var menuItem = $('.menu-item-template').html();

            menuItem = menuItem.replace(/MENUITEM/g,menuitems[i].name);

            var menuItem = $(menuItem);

            // attempting to add images to src attribute with a path
            menuItem.find('img').attr({
                alt : menuitems[i].name,
                // the actual image
                src : menuitems[i].filename
            });

            container.append(menuItem);

        }   


    }
```

How can this problem be solved ? It tried allocating relative paths to my project folder but that does not seem to solve the problem. I am using JavaScript to parse my JSON object.

Upon trying to display the images, the error I get in Chrome is :

```
GET file:///C:/Users:/Documents/App/html/sample_image.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: Why not use [relative path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29)?

Comment: I don't understand what I am doing wrong with my relative path. I tried appending a '../images/<image-file>' to the src attribute and this does not display any images.

Comment: Please show me your absolute path to your image and page. It works with both. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/a825wqLe/1/) fiddle. Best way is to look in your debuging-tool (e. g. Firebug) and inspect the img tag.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem with the "menuitems", the better way is to using relative path as Jan Hommes said. Another bad way is to adding new "replace" statement to replace the path  to relative path.

At the end, strongly recommended to using relative path in web site.